# R select multiple rows by conditional row number

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a R dataframe like this one:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(6,7,8,9,10)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
colnames(df)<-c("a","b")

df
  a  b
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```

I would like to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd AND 5th row of the column `a`, so `1 2 3 5`, by selecting rows by their number.

I have tried `df$a[1:3,5]` but I get `Error in df$a[1:3, 5] : incorrect number of dimensions`.
What DOES work is `c(df$a[1:3],df$a[5])` but I was wondering if there was an easier way to achieve this with R?

Comment: did you try `df[c(1:3, 5), "a")]` ?

Comment: try `df[df[c(1:3, 5),1], ]` .

Comment: @Mamoun Benghezal It works with `df[c(1:3, 5), "a"]` (without the bracket ;))! Thanks! So there is a need for the `c()` command anyway

Comment: @Ruthger Righart `df[c(1:3, 5),1]` would be perfect too!

Comment: @tlorin: ok great! the difference is in the output. Your code selects only the vector "a" while my solution selects the rows of the entire data frame as a function of the values given in column "a".  Of course this depends on what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data frame has two dimensions (rows and columns).  When you use the square brackets to extract values, R expects everything prior to the comma to indicate the rows desired, and everything after the comma to indicate the columns desired (see: [`?[`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)).  Hence, `df[1:3,5]` means rows 1 through 3, from column 5.  To turn your desired rows into a single vector, you need to concatenate (i.e., `c(1:3,5)`).  That would all go before the comma, the column indicator, `1` or `"a"`, would go after the comma.  Thus, `df[c(1:3,5), 1]` is what you need.

---

For alternative answer (that might be  more appropriate to a dataframe with many more columns), `df[c(1:3, 5), "a"]` as suggested by @Mamoun Benghezal would also get it done!

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation! I edited your answer to include the suggestion of @Mamoud Benghezal :)

Comment: @tlorin, it's fine to use that. I don't know that it is any more usable for a data frame w/ many columns, though.

Comment: I was just thinking that if you have a dataframe with 100 columns with column names it might be easier to get the values of interest by the column name, instead of counting to get the good column number ;)